# Dropped HDD - Any chance of data recovery

Tags: hard-drive

So a friend of mine dropped his HDD and now it is not recognised even in the BIOS.
He told me he turned it on a few times after the incident, which is probably what killed it completely if the heads got misaligned by the impact.

Here is a recording of it turning on and off in an enclosure: https://vocaroo.com/i/s1mTMbX7jZb8

Do you reckon there is any chance to recover anything?
I read about the freezer fix.

Thanks

Comment: If it is not recognized in the BIOS, recovery it beyond your capability. If the data on the drive is valuable enough, you may seek professional assistance from a data recovery service, but because they'll have to physically repair the drive (not to use it again, but only to access the data) it will cost $$$$$

Comment: Recovering the data yourself will not be possible, if the data is important enough, send it to professionals.  The disk as-is cannot and should not be used, the use of the drive will decrease any chance of data recovery by professionals

Comment: Professional data recovery is not an option. The data in question are personal pictures, which are not extremely important.
In this case there are 2 choices now: bin the drive or open it and hope for the best.
What do you think?

Comment: You cannot fix the drive. You don’t have the tools nor the experience. It is, without a shadow of a doubt, impossible for you to read a single byte off this drive. Your only option is to send it in for professional data recovery. Listen to what people are telling you. But by all means open the drive up and look at all the pretty parts because after that it is unlikely even a data recovery company will touch it.

Comment: @Appleoddity Your message sounds like your well-being depends on my inability to fix this drive. Very condescending indeed.

Opening it won't do much harm, considering the circumstances. At least I will see the pretty parts.

Comment: No. The well-being of your data depends on your believing that it is impossible for you to do anything with the drive. You might want to consider what everyone has said after suggesting freezing the drive was worthy of mention. If the data is of no importance to you then, like I said, by all means open it up and observe. The drive will be unrecoverable after that. But at least you can learn whatever you can by it. There are some neodymium magnets you can play with. They work good for magnetizing screwdrivers.

Comment: I love taking the magnets out of dead hard drives.  They're good for lots of stuff, such as attaching a very thick stack of papers to your refrigerator. ;)

Comment: The simplest option, of course, would be to just get a new drive & restore to it from backup.

Comment: "Opening it won't do much harm" - Most data recovery companies will not even attempt data recovery on a HDD if you open it up yourself.  Sounds like data recovery isn't that important.  Restore the photos from your backup.

Comment: More than likely the read arm has dislodged, send it to a professional recovery company for any chance to recover data....http://www.lowcostrecovery.com/

Answer (score 1):

If the plates inside the HDD hadn't lost alignment with the axis (what lowers the cost, but also in other case is possible), there is chance to recover the data. If the data is valuable you can give the disk to company that reads the data from the plates. However this is really expensive - you may have to pay few thousand dollars for all the data from the drive.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely you will be able to recover the data yourself, but there are a few things you can try.  **Opening the drive is not one of them** - if the drive is not recognised by the PC that implies a logic board failure, not a platter issue, and opening the disk will only compound your problems.

Everything below this is a long shot, and might recover your data, or might make it harder/impossible to revover. Do not proceed unless you have ruled out engaging a professional company.

The 2 most common options would be to put in disk in a bag and freeze it. Then plug it in and  see if it's recognised - even only briefly. If it is, you may be able to use a tool like ddrescue to get data till it stops, freeze and repeat.

You might also want to try examining and reseating the control board - this will not require exposing the platters.

The last common solution is to try heating ie in an oven on a low heat.

Comment: The drive not being detected does not mean the logic board is broken. Part of the firmware is located on the disk itself, the logic board only contains bootstrap code. With the mechanical parts malfunctioning, the drive simply cannot complete its boot sequence.

Comment: @DanielB I'm skeptical of your assertion, and could not find evidence to support it in Google - it could be bad Google-fu though. Can you provide for this assertion? (My skepticism stems from an understanding that factory initialisation stores info about the disk on the controller, and swapping controllers can have unintended side effects as a result)

Comment: Sure, here you go: http://www.databe.com/articles/article6.html There are some other references around the net, though nothing as solid.

Comment: @DanielB - Thanks for this.  TIL....